# embedded linux, application state freeze, relaunch

Tags: c, linux, embedded, arm, embedded-linux

We have an embedded application, now it requires its state to be saved and reloaded. Just like in PC games, where you save it before you have to go out and breath some fresh air.The product is quiet evolutionary in nature, no proper design so identifying data to be saved is not an option.

The software is in C so all data has fixed addresses (.data segment), its also deterministic,a and no dynamic memory allocations. So theoretically I take a back up of this data segment in a file and on relaunch of application update it back from the file. This approach will probably save a lot more data than what is required, but I am ok with it.

How can I do this in short execution time ?
Also how can I identify the start and end of .data segment in run-time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [application checkpointing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing), so perhaps the [Berkley Lab Checkpoint Restart](https://ftg.lbl.gov/projects/CheckpointRestart/) library might help you.

You could perhaps use the [mmap(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) system call, if you are sure all the data has fixed addresses, etc...

To know about your current memory segments and mappings, read (from your application) the `/proc/self/maps`  file. There is also `/proc/self/smaps` etc. Learn more about [proc(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc), ie `/proc/`