# Loading memory dumps in C (similar to PHP serialize)

Tags: php, c, linux

I have a C program that when started, it reads a lot of configuration files, user settings and store it all in memory.

The thing is that this c tool is run many times and these initial steps to read the config, parse the settings, etc are taking a long time.

I was thinking on running all these steps once and saving the memory somewhere and then only reading that memory dump next time it runs (kinda like a cache).

It is possible in C? I was thinking something similar to a serialize/unserialize in PHP to parse the content from memory...

*update: I can't save the content of the settings in a file and only re-read that during startup, because the memory content is a bit complicated. The settings are read for many users and a complicated hash/list is built in memory, with multiple child elements, regex calls, etc. The idea is to save that final structure somewhere and re-use every time..

Comment: How is this cache being built? A single struct malloc'd() and in contiguous memory space? Or a whole bunch of different mallocs() spread out all over? The single struct is easy to write out - you just use the struct's pointer and presumably know how long the memory block is. If it's a bunch of different memory chunks, you're in for a lot of work.

Comment: Whatever you create will still need to be parsed, I doubt you would gain much, if anything (unless your initial config file is in some ridiculously complicated format). After all, you can't serialize memory *pointers*, can you?

Comment: Marc: multiple mallocs everywhere. At the end, it becomes like an internal tree/list, with multiple child elements, pointers, next->, child->, etc. Each of those have contents from files saved in memory, complex regexes that are compiled and some other ugliness

Comment: Perhaps you could look at using shared memory or alternatively `mmap` to save your assembled memory structures.

Comment: William: thanks! So with mmap, can I share a memory structure, like config->userdata, so other proccess can access config->userdata and just read it?

Comment: See also this answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10018465/841108

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a shared memory segment with something like sysv shm and let the program fill in the data the first time it is run. The following times it can just attach to the same memory segment (using shmat/shmget).